# Why does MacKenzie McHale retain her cut-glass English accent?

Tags: character, the-newsroom

It seems hard to believe that MacKenzie McHale from *The Newsroom* would retain her very English accent in view of her many years spent with Americans. She seems to identify closely with the USA. Is there an obvious reason why she would have retained her English accent so firmly?

Comment: I'm confused... It takes actors effort to speak in an accent other than their native accent. Why would she do that all the time?

Comment: Craig Ferguson has been living in LA for more than 25 years (more than half his life), has become a US citizen, and I would consider him a patriot (although an unusual one). His Scottish accent is as thick as they come. John Oliver is also living in the US, became a US citizen, is married to a US citizen, and retains his British accent. Also … Schwarzenegger.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Emily Mortimer explains the origins of the accent in [this interview with the Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/tvandradio/10625039/Emily-Mortimer-In-England-people-think-my-success-is-down-to-my-famous-father.html):

> While she was forced to make an unexpected temporary move to LA,
>   Mortimer did manage to retain her own accent for the role. “Mackenzie
>   was originally supposed to be American, and thank God she isn’t any
>   more. **I don’t know how I would have kept up that accent. Aaron’s
>   incredible dialogue is hard enough in my own accent**,” she says. “Very
>   early on in the rehearsals, I asked: ‘Is there any reason she can’t be
>   British?’
>
> "And **then Aaron got into the idea of this demented half-breed
>   American-born, British-raised person talking in this passionate, proud
>   way about America**. It takes the curse off some of the more idealistic
>   stuff, to have this character who talks in that way without it being
>   jingoistic, without the chest-beating. But it happened mainly because
>   I didn’t think I could keep up the accent."

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion:  It depends on the person. From my experience, I am pretty sure of it.

I had a British girl friend who was born in the UK, but lived and worked in the US for at least 10 years (all the while interacting with Americans and our accents). As far as I could tell, her accent was exactly her British accent -- it had nothing to do with the California accent we were living in.

I, on the other hand, lived in various parts of the US over the years -- and my accent subtly changed to some hybrid without me thinking about it or trying to do anything about it.

Actors are experts in creating accents, but they do not have to for the sake of being realistic.